# Installing a Virtual Machine with no VT-X available

Tags: sas, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

*I have a Windows 8.1 x64 installed on my computer with an Intel Processor who does not support VT-x.*

For the school, **I need to install SAS University Edition on a Virtual Machine.**

I tried to install Virtual Box and VMWare but when I launch my machine, I have the error "VT-x is not enabled", seems logic.

**Do you have a solution on how to use SAS on a computer who does not support VT-x ?**

I searched all over the intenet but I'm totally screwed :D

Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: So what CPU you are using and did you try to enable VT-x in BIOS?

Comment: Are you allowed to [run it on AWS](https://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/AWS_runvApp.htm) instead?

Answer (score 1):

SAS can run easily in a Hyper-V session. Go into your BIOS, as Lee suggested, and enable virtualization. Then add Windows features, install hyper-V. If your CPU does not support this (and it would need to be very old), use Azure or AWS (I recommend Azure, personally).

I have had SAS running in Hyper-V before and in Azure. Both work fine. For help, please tell us the CPU and information regarding your system. Use Speccy to get the details.

Memory will also be key. A VM will need enough space to run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

My CPU is this one : https://ark.intel.com/content/www/fr/fr/ark/products/69669/intel-pentium-processor-b980-2m-cache-2-40-ghz.html

It says that VT-x is not available for this CPU.

I tried to enable virtualization in BIOS but I have a SONY Vaio and I don't find the advanced settings in BIOS, and I'm not even sure I can enable it regarding the specifications of my processor...

Should I use Hyper-V or use Azure ?

Comment: That processor does not have virtualization support: http://cpuboss.com/cpu/Intel-Pentium-B980. Use Azure. Get a free account and a small VM: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/virtual-machines/search/?&OCID=AID2000128_SEM_lzYhatX9&MarinID=lzYhatX9_78821302128519_%2Bvirtualization_bb_c__1261139887056897_kwd-78821266183032:loc-190&lnkd=Bing_Azure_Nonbrand&msclkid=5cccad8c6c251dc0e739f017e8a21e45&ef_id=XZGYPQAAAPk3nNzc:20191007183139:s&dclid=CKnzjJrkiuUCFUY-TwodbCIJrw

Consider getting a new machine when resources permit it. The architecture is very old.